# Reading a series of strings into a char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

This is the code in the main() portion of the program:

```
 int numFiles;
 cout << "How many signal files are there?";
 cin >> numFiles;

 char singalFiles[numFiles][100];

 string backgroundFile;

 for (int i=0;i<numFiles;i++){
    string singalFile;
    cout << "Please input the name of singal file" << i << ".";
    cin >> singalFile;

    singalFile >> char singalFiles[i][100];

    string backgroundFile;
    cout << "Please input the name of background file" << i << ".";
    cin >> singalFile;

    backgroundFile >> char backgroundFiles [i][100];
 }
```

This is the code I am writing as part of a research project. I was wondering if somebody could help me with this. I am very new to c++ and do not know how to get the strings to write into a char array.

I am having trouble reading the strings into the char array so they can be stored there. That is, I am trying to read each of the strings called backgroundFile and signalFile into the char arrays backgroundFiles and singalFiles.

Comment: "`char signalFiles[numFiles][100];`": Are you allowed to use a `std::vector` instead, or is this one of those classes where you're forced to use a crippled subset of C++?  The construct you're using there is illegal for standard C++; it's a variable length array.  If you need to create an array when the size isn't known at compiletime, you will have to allocate memory for it with `new`, or use a container class.  Anyway, I think you're also looking for `strncpy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition `char singalFiles[numFiles][100];` may be an issue as standard C++ requires the size of an array be constant.  Some compilers accept this as an extension, but you shouldn't rely on it.

But as easy alternative, you can use [vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and strings:

```
vector<string> singalFiles(numFiles);
```

Then you can easily read the data:

```
   //cin >> singalFile;   ==> combine with the next line
   // singalFile >> char singalFiles[i][100];
   cin >> singalFiles[i];
```

You don't even have to reserve for the size in advance.  You could as well do:

```
vector<string> singalFiles;  // the size of a vector is dynamic anyway !   
... 
cin >> singalFile;  // as you did before
signalFiles.push_back(signalFile);  // add a new element to the end of the vector.
```

Comment: Thank you. This is really helpful. So i need to read on vectors in C++?

Comment: @ForrestChanningHunter yes ! Absolutely !

Comment: @ForrestChanningHunter: NO!... you need to pick a good book about C++ and read it cover-to-cover, not just `std::vector`. Using C++ without reading about it is a real disaster, no matter how smart you are (actually being smart makes things worse, because sometimes the correct answer is not the logical one). Pick a good book from http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/320726 and do your future yourself a big favor.

Comment: @ForrestChanningHunter Start with The C++ Primer, newest edition (Not The C++ Primer Plus).  If you're not using the standard container classes, algorithms, you're not programming C++, but even worse, you're working too hard!

Comment: Thanks guys! I appreciate it. I will start reading tonight. I am also using Xcode to develop and compile the code, so is c++ standard on all the compilers and IDE's?