# How to use push back method for a C++ vector

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

```
int numFiles;
cout << "How many signal files are there?";
cin >> numFiles;

vector<string> signalFiles(numFiles);
vector<string> backgroundFiles(numFiles);

string backgroundFile;

for (int i=0;i<numFiles;i++){

    string singalFiles;
    cout << "Please input the name of singal file" << i << ".";
    cin >> singalFiles[i];
    signalFiles.push_back(signalFiles());

    string backgroundFiles;
    cout << "Please input the name of background file" << i << ".";
    cin >> backgroundFiles[i];
    backgroundFiles.push_back(backgroundFiles.str());

}
```

How would I go about using the push_back method for the given vectors?

I get the following error message in the code:

```
No member named 'str' in 'std::__1::basic_string<char>'
```

I am confused as to why I am receiving this message.

Comment: if this is actually your code, then you have a typo: you have `cin>>singalFiles[i];` instead of `cin>>signalFiles[i];`

Comment: Why do the string variables exist? You read directly into the vectors. The `push_back` lines don't seem to be accomplishing anything. You're making the code harder than it has to be: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b9e506b56e4e738

Comment: Why do you have string variables with almost the same name as vector ones?

Comment: Wow... you're sure a fast reader. Learning C++ in 45 minutes is impossible, but even reading C++ Primer in such a short time is impressive...

Comment: Oh, I see. You seem to be combining the two methods mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28637477/962089), but they both accomplish the same thing. Usually, you'll pick one of either reserving space in a vector and reading the elements directly (`std::cin >> signalFiles[i]`) or reading into a temporary variable and adding it to the vector (`std::string temp; std::cin >> temp; signalFiles.push_back(temp);`). Which one to use depends on whether you know how many to read beforehand.

Comment: thank you Chris. that seemed to work. I just started C++ about 3 hours ago. appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. you are pre-allocating the `size()` of each `std::vector`, which means you are pre-filling them with blank values.  Then you are reading into those existing elements (which is fine) and also `push_back()`ing what you have already stored (which is wrong).  So, either stop pre-allocating the `size()` (you can use the `reserve()` method to pre-allocate the `capacity()` instead) so you can use `push_back()` correctly, or else use the vector `[]` operator to assign the existing elements and remove the `push_back()` altogether.
2. Your `backgroundFiles` string variable is in conflict with your `backgroundFiles` vector variable (same name being used).  You need to rename them so they are unique.
3. `std::string` does not have `str()` or `operator()` members. You declared your `std::vector` containers to hold `std::string` elements, and the values you are reading from `std::cin` are already `std::string` types, so just store them as-is.
4. You are using `cin >>` over and over without taking line breaks into account. That `>>` operator stops reading when it encounters whitespace, not when it encounters a line break. You should switch to `std::getline()` instead.

Try this instead:

```
int numFiles = 0;
cout << "Please input the number of signal files:";
if (!(cin >> numFiles)) {
    // error reading the number, do something
}
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

vector<string> signalFiles, backgroundFiles;
signalFiles.reserve(numFiles);
backgroundFiles.reserve(numFiles);

for (int i = 0; i < numFiles; ++i) {

    string signalFile;
    cout << "Please input the name of signal file " << i+1 << ":";
    if (!getline(cin, signalFile)) {
        // error reading the string, do something
        break;
    }
    signalFiles.push_back(signalFile);

    string backgroundFile;
    cout << "Please input the name of background file " << i+1 << ":";
    if (!getline(cin, backgroundFile)) {
        // error reading the string, do something
        break;
    }
    backgroundFiles.push_back(backgroundFile);
}
```

Or this:

```
int numFiles = 0;
cout << "Please input the number of signal files:";
if (!(cin >> numFiles)) {
    // error reading the number, do something
}
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

vector<string> signalFiles(numFiles);
vector<string> backgroundFiles(numFiles);

for (int i = 0; i < numFiles; ++i) {

    string signalFile;
    cout << "Please input the name of signal file " << i+1 << ":";
    if (!getline(cin, signalFile)) {
        // error reading the string, do something
        break;
    }
    signalFiles[i] = signalFile;

    string backgroundFile;
    cout << "Please input the name of background file " << i+1 << ":";
    if (!getline(cin, backgroundFile)) {
        // error reading the string, do something
        break;
    }
    backgroundFiles[i] = backgroundFile;
}
```

I prefer the first approach, as the vector `size()` will accurately reflect how many files were successfully read and pushed.  With the second approach, if an error occurs, the vector `size()` will include the default blank values that were not overwritten.